# Python/Django using a sort of cache to registered errors for a period of time

Tags: python-3.x

In a Python/Django app, in case of an error I sent an email. The code logic looks like this:

```
  if canvas(path, size):
        json[key] = path
    else:
        # send an error email 
        send_error_email(error_msg='Canvas Error')
        raise CanvasError
```

`send_error_email` is a function that sends email
`canvas(path, size)` is function that returns `True` or `False`

I other errors/exceptions that send emails.

My issue is that if there are situations where I receive the same error multiple times per hour.

What I want is a solution to `cache` in a way the error, and if is the same error not to send the email.

Also to clean this `cache` after a predefined period of time.

My approach is to use as a cache an array, and append to it:

```
   error_cache.append(error)
```

But how do I clean the cache after a time, also avoid cleaning the errors created let's say in the last 20minutes(need to variate, 20 is just as an example).

Comment: *if is the same error* --> How to decide whether it's the same error? What makes two errors same?

Comment: the error_msg, the argument for send_error_email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your errors are strings or any hashable and comparable type, one approach you could follow is to use a `set`.

```
import time
errorCache = set()
startTime = time.time()
```

And add this at the beginning of your loop or wherever you find it most appropriate:

```
if time.time() - startTime > 1200 # It's been more than 20 min since the last error
     errorCache.clear()
     startTime = time.time()
```

Whenever you're about to send a mail (for e.g., when there's a canvas error), you do this instead:

```
error = 'Canvas Error'
if error not in errorCache:
    send_error_email(error_msg=error)
    errorCache.add(error)
raise CanvasError
```